# how do I plot 2 figures under eachother with mathplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a bunch of figures to show which only make true sense when compared to eachother.
So I have colorvalues in RGB and in HSV throughout frames of video set on axes.
I do this with this method:

```
    def plotcolors(self,colors, title):
    # colors.sort(key=itemgetter(2))

    blue = [item[0] for item in colors]
    green = [item[1] for item in colors]
    red = [item[2] for item in colors]

    plt.title("timeseries")
    plt.plot(blue, color='blue')
    plt.plot(red, color='red')
    plt.plot(green, color='green')
    plt.xlabel("Number of Frame")
    plt.ylabel("RGB-value")
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
```

this gives me: [image]

Now I do the same for HSV which gives me:
[image]

so both times I calculate a series of RGB or HSV values, keep them in an array and with that array call def plotcolors()

Now I'd really love to see those 2 under eachother, in 1 figure so I can show the differences.
I tried this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
    fig.suptitle('Aligning x-axis using sharex')
    blue = [item[0] for item in aver_diff]
    green = [item[1] for item in aver_diff]
    red = [item[2] for item in aver_diff]

    #     Plot timeseries RGB
    plt.title("RGB timeseries")
    plt.plot(blue, color='blue')
    plt.plot(red, color='red')
    plt.plot(green, color='green')

    ax1.plot(blue, red, green)
    blue = [item[0] for item in aver_diff_ref]
    green = [item[1] for item in aver_diff_ref]
    red = [item[2] for item in aver_diff_ref]

    #     Plot timeseries RGB
    plt.title("HSV timeseries")
    plt.plot(blue, color='blue')
    plt.plot(red, color='red')
    plt.plot(green, color='green')
    ax2.plot(blue,red, green)
```

But then I get this:
[image]

Now I have to add, above figure only appears (when testing) after I call:

```
  self.plotcolors(aver_diff, "Average colors holo ROI in RGB")
```

which is the statement I, up until now, used to plot RGB values and later on other values.
If anyone could give some insight into what I'm doing wrong or how to do it right, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `plt.subplots` you can access plots using `ax1` and `ax2` instead of `plt`. Here is your code with some changes and it should work.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
fig.suptitle('Aligning x-axis using sharex')

blue = [item[0] for item in aver_diff]
green = [item[1] for item in aver_diff]
red = [item[2] for item in aver_diff]

#     Plot timeseries RGB
ax1.set_title("RGB timeseries")
ax1.plot(blue, color='blue')
ax1.plot(red, color='red')
ax1.plot(green, color='green')

blue = [item[0] for item in aver_diff_ref]
green = [item[1] for item in aver_diff_ref]
red = [item[2] for item in aver_diff_ref]

#     Plot timeseries RGB
ax2.set_title("HSV timeseries")
ax2.plot(blue, color='blue')
ax2.plot(red, color='red')
ax2.plot(green, color='green')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research I found a solution:

```
plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(211)
    self.plotcolors(aver_diff, "Average colors holo ROI in RGB")
    plt.subplot(212)
    self.plotcolors(aver_diff_ref, "Average colors non-ROI in RGB")
    plt.show()
```

The only thing I had to do is erase the plt.show() in the plotcolors method. Then it gets me this:
[image]

That only leaves me with tidying up the titles and axis names.